# What domains do I need to whitelist for updates?

Tags: updates

My IT department are moving my server to a more secure location that has limited web access, they want to know what the minimum web access is to maintain the servers updates and repositories. Is there a list of 'white-listed' sites available to give them?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Just allow the `*ubuntu.com` domain as well as `*.launchpad.net` and you will be able to get updates from the official repositories and PPAs.